# Changing the look and feel of the JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, applet, jfilechooser, look-and-feel

I am using a net beans form to create an applet.  The applet relies on a JFileChooser.  If I write the program as an application instead of an applet, the file chooser looks different.  Why does the same code produce different looking file choosers when written as an applet or an application?  Also, how can I change the look and feel of my file chooser from the applet to look like the file chooser from the application?

Application file chooser:

[image]

Applet file chooser:

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that it is only the file chooser which looks different?

Comment: @Holger that is correct

Comment: Do you have an invocation of `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()` in your application? If that happens when some parts of the UI are already created, these parts will look different than the part created afterwards. You may invoke [`updateUI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#updateUI--) on a component to update it to the current look and feel. The question is which part shows the current look&feel, the file chooser or the rest of the UI…

Comment: The app. is using Nimbus, while the applet is using Metal.  I would recommend instead of *either,* using  the [System Look And Feel Class Name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#getSystemLookAndFeelClassName--).  Here is an [example of the Windows PLAF on a file chooser](http://i.stack.imgur.com/O0eWK.png).

Comment: @Holger That worked put it in an answer and Ill approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke [`UIManager.setLookAndFeel(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#setLookAndFeel-java.lang.String-) in your application, existing components are not automatically updated as there is no global registry of all existing component. Hence, these components will look different than the components created afterwards. You may invoke [`updateUI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#updateUI--) on a component to update it to the current look and feel. There is also the utility method [`SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#updateComponentTreeUI-java.awt.Component-) which will call `updateUI()` on an entire component tree, recursively.

But generally, it’s better to set the desired look and feel as early as possible, preferably before creating any component, to avoid the necessity to update existing components.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`UIManager.setLookAndFeel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#setLookAndFeel(javax.swing.LookAndFeel))

Comment: How do I reference only the JFileChooser

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(JFileChooser);
```